# Running ContactsApp.getContact(email) inside a loop causes timeout

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I'm creating a GAS for Gmail.

The first part of this script is collecting all recipients and senders from a thread object from the GmailApp. No problem there, except I'm just left with an array of strings with the `"full name <email>"` syntax.

Secondly, I want to create a card for each contact email, by first looking up the contact object inside the ContactsApp. This however causes the script to time out, even though logs show it is able to fetch the contacts.

I've tested 2 alternatives:

1. get all contacts with `ContactsApp.getContacts()` and there's no timeout.
2. look up a single contact with `CotnactsApp.getContact(email)`an no timeout either.

```
  // TEST 1: Get All Contacts
  var allContacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();

  // TEST 2: Get one contact
  var testContact = ContactsApp.getContact("test@email.com");

  // TEST 3: Loop over and get contacts
  var threadContacts = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
    var email =  participants[i].split("<")[1].split(">")[0];
    var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(email);
    threadContacts.push(contact)
  }
```

So I'm a bit unclear here as to the intended usage. Should I go for option 1 and load all the contacts on the client side and iterate through these? Or is it intended to look for a contact each time I need to get the data? Doesn't loading all contact risks loading a gazillion contacts (should someone have so many?). It seems cumbersome.

I couldn't see any guidelines on the documentation.

Comment: You may have better luck using the actual People api via UrlFetchApp rather than ContactsApp. It probably makes sense to offer a paginated list of contact cards, especially since there may be many that are involved in the email thread. That will help your UI remain timely.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the contact object by searching the emails.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, the contact objects are retrieved by searching the emails from `ContactsApp.getContacts()`. This method is also mentioned in your question.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Create an array by retrieving `email` from `"full name <email>"`.
2. Retrieve all contacts.
3. Retrieve the contact object by searching the emails from all contacts.

#### Sample script:

In this case, it supposes that `participants` is an array like `["full name <email1>", "full name <email2>",,,]`.

```
// Retrieve email address from "full name <tanaike@hotmail.com>" in participants and put them to an array.
var convertedParticipants = participants.map(function(e) {return e.split("<")[1].split(">")[0]});

var allContacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();

// Here, the contact objects are retrieved by searching the emails.
var results = allContacts.reduce(function(ar, c) {
  var emails = c.getEmails();
  if (emails.length > 0) {

    // Retrieve email addresses from a contact object and put them to an array.
    var addresses = emails.map(function(e) {return e.getAddress()});

    // When the emails of "convertedParticipants" are included in the contact object, the object is put to an array.
    if (convertedParticipants.some(function(f) {return addresses.indexOf(f) != -1})) {
      ar.push(c);
    }
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
```

- When above script is run, you can see the searched contact objects in `results` as an array.

#### References:

- [getEmails()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact.html#getEmails())
- [getAddress()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/email-field.html#getAddress())
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

When `var results = allContacts.reduce(function(ar, c) {###}, []);` is modified using the for loop, it becomes as follows.

#### Script:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allContacts.length; i++) {
  var emails = allContacts[i].getEmails();
  if (emails.length > 0) {
    var addresses = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
      addresses.push(emails[j].getAddress());
    }
    var f = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < convertedParticipants.length; j++) {
      if (addresses.indexOf(convertedParticipants[j]) != -1) {
        f = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (f) {
      results.push(allContacts[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You understood my goal and I understand the overall flow. However I am not familiar with in-line function syntax you're using, so I'm not able to exactly follow the answer. :)

Comment: PS: I'm working on a getContacts() + getEmails() + getAddress() solution. However, it's taking quite some time to load contacts and iterate through the contact array. For a 4 participants email thread, it takes about 6 seconds to load. It's a little strange that it should take so long. No?

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you that my answer could resolve your issue? If my answer was incomplete, I would like to modify. About `PS:` of your replying, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `PS:`, I cannot image your current script. So I cannot correctly answer to it. But at Google Apps Script, the process cost is not stable. So for example, when the benchmark is measured, it is required to use the large population. So about `6 seconds to load`, I'm not sure whether it might be the reasonable. About this, I apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: no need to apologize. Your solution shows a possible way to handle the problem. However, I am not exactly able to produce your code, since I do not understand the in-line function syntax. I've worked on a similar solution using the same workflow and the 6 seconds to load for 4 participants is way too slow and suggests this may not be the right way to go about getting contact information.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for quick reply. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I am not exactly able to produce your code`. I understood about your question like `You want to retrieve the contact object by searching the emails.`. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. And also if my sample script couldn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, I would like to modify it. I would like to resolve your issue.

Comment: @Benjamin I added the explanation for the sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks. I get the workflow.. So reduce() is used instead of a for loop iterating over the contact list? I'm using a for loop. Is reduce() a better tool?

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for replying. In your question, I also understood that you want to reduce the process cost of the script. So I used `reduce()` because when I measured the process cost of loop process, the cost of `reduce` is lower than that of the for loop. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6) But as a sample script, I added one more sample that `var results = allContacts.reduce(function(ar, c) {###}, []);` was modified with the for loop. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for replying. If my sample script didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to think of the solution of it.